# Excel: Dynamic formula for change unit size in KB, MB, GB, TB, etc... Automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to correct the formula to be dynamic for all units KB, MB, GB, TB, etc ... It works perfectly for MB and GB but does not work for other units. my formula is:

```
{=IF(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A10,LEN(A1:A10)-3))+0),VALUE(LEFT(A1:A10,LEN(A1:A10)-3))+0))>=1000,TEXT(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A10,LEN(A1:A10)-3))+0),VALUE(LEFT(A1:A10,LEN(A1:A10)-3))+0))/1024,"0.00")&" GB",TEXT(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A10,LEN(A1:A10)-3))+0),VALUE(LEFT(A1:A10,LEN(A1:A10)-3))+0)),"0.00")&" MB")}
```

[image: Excel Formula DEMO]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE:

```
=ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A4,FIND(" ",A1:A4)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A4,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3))/(10^(INT((LEN(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A4,FIND(" ",A1:A4)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A4,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3)))-1)/3)*3)),2) & " " & INDEX({"KB","MB","GB","TB"},INT((LEN(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A4,FIND(" ",A1:A4)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A4,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3)))-1)/3))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @Scoot Craner try change 100 GB + 1 MB + 1 MB + 10 MB = 100.012 TB the result is FALSE.

Comment: @Scoot Craner It works perfectly just how to round result to Maximum 2 decimals? Decimals vary depending on the results.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in `ROUND()`: `=ROUND(TheAboveFormula,2)`

Comment: Also please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @Scoot Craner When put formula in =ROUND(formula,2) I get a mistake #VALUE!

Comment: give me a second

Comment: Brilliant, Works perfectly THAK YOU VERY VERY MUCH!

Comment: @Scoot Craner When I have empty cells in the range A1:A4 I get a Error: #VALUE! Please help me.

Comment: @SmekeriBezPrezimena Can you just put "0 MB" in the empty cells? The formula will work with that.

Comment: @Mistella Is it possible to avoid the error without writing "0 MB" I want to be empty cells.

Comment: @SmekeriBezPrezimena yes but that is a new question.  Changes from the original question should get their own question.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this and it's working fine for me.

```
{=TEXT(SUM(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1:A4,FIND(" ",A1:A4,1)-1))*IF(RIGHT(A1:A4,2)="KB",1/1000000,IF(RIGHT(A1:A4,2)="MB",1/1000,IF(RIGHT(A1:A4,2)="GB",1,IF(RIGHT(A1:A4,2)="TB",1000,IF(RIGHT(A1:A4,2)="PB",1000000,0)))))),"0,00") & " GB"}
```

Comment: Not work for me: 1 MB + 1 MB + 1 MM + 10 MB = 0.01 GB. IF the result is <1000 = MB I want result 13 MB

Comment: @SmekeriBezPrezimena sorry i'm working with an Excel in French, i just forgot translating some functions... hope it's working now ? thx

Comment: Thank MikeR Scott Craner formula gives a better result.