# Excel: How to multiply with blanks cell in range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Formula Work Perfectly, however when I have empty cells in the range A1:A3 I get error: #VALUE! How to fix? Original Post: [Excel: Dynamic formula for change unit size in KB, MB, GB, TB, etc... Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55341361/excel-dynamic-formula-for-change-unit-size-in-kb-mb-gb-tb-etc-automatica/55381182)

Version: 1

```
=TRUNC(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3))/(10^(INT((LEN(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3)))-1)/3)*3)),2)&" "&INDEX({"KB","MB","GB","TB"},INT((LEN(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3)))-1)/3))
```

Version: 2

```
=TRUNC(SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4*10^(MATCH(B1:B4,{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3))/(10^(INT((LEN(SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4*10^(MATCH(B1:B4,{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3)))-1)/3)*3)),2)&" "&INDEX({"KB","MB","GB","TB"},INT((LEN(SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4*10^(MATCH(B1:B4,{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3)))-1)/3))
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data to help visualize your equations

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338711/excel-array-formula-to-skip-empty-cells) post. Take a look here.

Comment: @urdearboy see edit post.

Comment: @Matthew Salvatore Viglione I do not know how to combine my formula with formula from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338711/excel-array-formula-to-skip-empty-cells) post

Comment: @Cyril I try it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add `IFERROR` to capture the Error that come due to empty cells.

`IFERROR`Forces us to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter the formula and make it an array.  Since I had to use an array entry I changed to SUM to save some typing in this massive formula.

```
=TRUNC(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3),0))/(10^(INT((LEN(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3),0)))-1)/3)*3)),2)&" "&INDEX({"KB","MB","GB","TB"},INT((LEN(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3),0)))-1)/3))
```

Being an Array formula it **REQUIRES** the formula be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice guide that helps [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2524-excel-if-cell-blank-do-not-calculate.html).

To sum it up:

> To ignore a formula or don't calculate if the specific cell is blank in Excel, we need to check the specific cell is blank or not with IF function, if it's not blank, we can go ahead to calculate with original formula.
>
> `=IF(Specific Cell<>"",Original Formula,"")`

So you could try this:

`=IF(CELL_TO_CHECK_IF_BLANK<>"",INSERT_FORMULA_HERE,"")`

Comment: That will not work as the main formula is an array that iterates independent of the outer one you propose.

Comment: @Matthew Salvatore Viglione =IF(A1:A3<>"",TRUNC(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3))/(10^(INT((LEN(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3)))-1)/3)*3)),2)&" "&INDEX({"KB","MB","GB","TB"},INT((LEN(SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A3,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB"},0)*3)))-1)/3)),"") Not work for me.